# SparkSession Object has no attribute read_csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

Getting an error message while running the below commands using pyspark (Pycharm IDE)

spark=SparkSession.builder.master("local").appname("Sample").getOrCreate()
df=spark.read_csv('filename.csv')

Error: SparkSession object has no attribute read_csv

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect. Use `spark.read.csv(...)`

Answer (score 0):

spark needs to use `spark.read.csv(file_name)`

`read_csv(file_name)` is pandas function to read CSV files.

Don't get confused with pandas df and spark df.